# System.out to Unix line endings on Windows

Tags: java, newline

In Java, newly created output streams look at the system line separator property to decide between Unix and Windows line endings, but System.out has already been created by the time your program starts, so altering that property has no effect on that stream.

If you want `System.out` to use Unix line endings, despite running on Windows, is there a way to do this other than eschewing `println()` and always using `print("...\n")`?

Comment: What makes you think `System.out` does not do the right thing on Unix?

Comment: @Raedwald It does the right thing on Unix. I'm trying to get it to use Unix line endings on Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manually set `System.out`. I sometimes use it to redirect prints to a file.

For example:

```
System.setOutput(new PrintStream("whatever_file.txt"));
```

In a similar sense, you can change the `PrintStream` to take your line endings into account.

Alternatively you can directly set the property of the line ending character:

```
System.setProperty("line.separator", "\n");
```

This could also be done when creating the JVM by the usual property setter:

```
java -jar bla.jar -Dline.seperator='\n'
```